# UIWebView показывает QuickType-бар в CodeMirror

Tags: ios, uiwebview, swift4

Почему клавиатура в IOS показывает QuickType - бар, когда редактируешь код в CodeMirror внутри UIWebView, в то время, как в сафари такого не происходит?

[image: В приложении]
[image: В safari]

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разница в том, что Safari основана на WebKit. Плюс UIWebView deprecated. 
Из [документации](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview) по UIWebView:

> In apps that run in iOS 8 and later, use the WKWebView class instead of using UIWebView.
>
> В приложениях под iOS 8 и более поздних, используйте класс WKWebView вместо использования UIWebView.

Чтобы было поведение как в Сафари используйте WKWebView.

UIWebView:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

WKWebView:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Как только смогу, проверю! Не могли бы вы написать, чем еще отличаются UiWebView и WKWebView?

Comment: @Крендель Много отличий, можете даже в документации Apple посмотреть. Из основных - WKWebView работае быстрее, исполняется не на главном потоке, использует Nitro JavaScript engine, исполняет JavaScript код асинхронно и другое.

Comment: Да, это сработало! Спасибо! Пришлось координально переписать приложение под асинхронный JS и много других фич, но предиктивный набор исчез! Спасибо!